# Why doesn't the context menu appear in the center of the screen?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I read that the context menu should appear centered automatically, but my context menu changes positions based on where I click. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2v7a.png) is what happens when I click on the first list item (menu in the lower right corner), and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkuUZ.png) is what happens for the other items.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("E adesso?");
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    mvc.controller.setHDImage(getContext(), info.position);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.same_author_images:
            return true;
        case R.id.share:
            shareImage(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**context_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/same_author_images"
        android:title="Immagini stesso autore" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:title="Condividi" />
</menu>
```