# Context Menu assigned to a button not displayed at center of screen

Tags: android, button, contextmenu, center

I have a `ContextMenu` assigned to a button `button_home` that gives the user options to select from the list. Everything works fine but the menu is not displayed at the center of the screen and instead anchored to the view (beside the button) as seen in below picture.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_home);
        registerForContextMenu(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if (v.getId()==R.id.button_home){
            this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_contex_menu, menu);
        }
    }
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int selectedItemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (selectedItemId){
        case R.id.typeDesktop:
            mBrowserType = "Desktop";
            break;
        case R.id.typeEdge:
            mBrowserType = "Edge";
            break;
    } return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Why is my `ContextMenu` not displayed at the center of the screen?

I have found this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526166/why-doesnt-the-context-menu-appear-in-the-center-of-the-screen) with a similar question bu seems like no one has answered it yet!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090537/8089770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to my question is "NO", it is not possible.

Yes, the `ContextMenu` will be usually displayed at the center of the screen however when you assign it to a `Button` or a particular view (as in my case), it will be displayed at the center of that view which is not the main view (screen).

As the view of the button is limited to button size, the `ContextView` was supposed to be displayed at the center of that view but as there is no enough room left, it was displayed anchored to the button.

P.S: I ended up using an `AlertDialog`.